# How can I reset USB Hub in Windows XP without mouse / keyboard?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, usb, keyboard, mouse

I have a PC with a Windows XP installation in which the keyboard and mouse are not working anymore. The installation doesn't have a password set so it logs in automatically. In Windows, when I unplug and plug in the USB keyboard again, windows wants to install the USB Hub again. Unfortunately, I can't click on "Next" to confirm the dialog.

I tried to reset the BIOS settings. The keyboard does work in BIOS and if I boot Ubuntu from a CD, everything works fine. So I really assume this is a Windows XP problem.

Also, I tried a PS/2 mouse, but unfortunately that doesn't work either. I checked BIOS settings for PS/2 as well, everything looks fine.

So, is there any way I can manipulate the files on the C: drive in another PC / from a Linux live CD to "reset" the usb hub ? My next step would be to re-install Windows XP, but of course it would be nice if there was a simpler way. Also, I could start the repair console, but I don't know what to do there actually..

Thanks!

Comment: Repair console ? Not sure what are you talking about but try system restore

Comment: Do a repair install of XP. http://www.wikihow.com/Do-a-Windows-XP-%22Repair-Install%22

Comment: Use a XP with SP3 install disk to do the repair.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. In step 7, I'm supposed to get a list of existing installations. Instead, I see a list of partitions and can only start a new installation in drive C:. It does warn me that "another os is installed here already" and the new installation would override it.

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like: You're right, it's called Recovery Console in the English version. See here: https://www.winhelp.us/recovery-console-in-windows-xp.html. How can I do a system restore without mouse and keyboard inside Windows ?

Comment: Ah, I realised that it's a home edition, the CD i used was professional. Tried a home CD and got the option now!  Unfortunately during the first reboot and finish of the setup, i need to confirm a dialog and the keyboard doesn't work at this point. Will probably do a fresh install..

Comment: @socken23 I would still suggest System Restore. As you said Linux Live CD Works just fine for you, so you should be able to boot from [ERD Commander](http://calmit.org/using-erd-commander-for-windows-xp/) as well. Once booted from it, do a system restore

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Was able to do a system restore now. Still no mouse, will definitely do a fresh install now. Thanks anyway!